# How to get some subset from a set? (Algorithm needs...)

Tags: algorithm, subset-sum

There is a version of the subset problem that asks if it is possible to find a subset of a set of integers that add up to the sum of the numbers not in the subset. Anyone know what the algorithm is?
Thanks

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/443712/algorithm-to-find-subset-within-two-sets-of-integers-whose-sums-match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [Partition problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem).